# Making gridview items clickable one by one

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

Level Selection GridView Image

[image]

I need to make Level 1 clickable and rest non clickable and when user clicks Level 1 it should make Level 2 clickable and rest non-clickable and so on so forth. Also if user is at Level 5 gridview should be clickable from level 1 to 4

```
myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity());
    gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

               //do something

                       }

private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridObject object = my.get(position);
        GridObject revers=reverseobj.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_set, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (check.get(position).equals("true"))
        {
            holder.text.setImageResource(revers.getName());
        }
        else {
            holder.text.setImageResource(object.getName());

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return my.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}


public class GridObject extends ArrayList<GridObject> {

private int image;
private int state;

public GridObject(int name, int state) {
    super();
    this.image = name;
    this.state = state;
}

public int getName() {
    return image;
}

public void setName(int name) {
    this.image = name;
}

public int getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(int state) {
    this.state = state;
}   
}
```

Comment: What you have done so far to achieve same?

Comment: Disable all items then enable only the one you need to be clickable.

Comment: Do you have any model for your gridView. share some code so that we can help you :)

Comment: Any ideas......?

Comment: @AbdulManan How about in `onItemClick()` you compare `position` with your current level and decide whether or not to process the click event? What challenge are you facing exactly?

Comment: yes @parsadpawar That's exactly what I have Done And My task is completed.
Thanks Everyone for your help and support......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Used a Simple Check list boolean = gridview items and It Works....By Default I have set the first value true and the rest value false.......

```
           gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
        id)
        {


               if (clickcheck.get(position).equals(true)) {
                 //complete some task then

                      position=position+1;
                clickcheck.remove(position);
                clickcheck.add(position,true);
               }
               else
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click On Level "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you want a "current level" that allows you to check/uncheck any grid item up to that level and allow you also to click on the item for the next level to make that the new current level.

If so, then it is simple to modify your adapter by adding a `currentLevel` variable and adjusting `getView()` to enable clicking on items up to and including this level.

Here is an updated version of your adapter showing this:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    // implement check as boolean array rather than what appears to be string array
    private final SparseBooleanArray check  = new SparseBooleanArray();
    // keep track of the current level
    private int currentLevel = 0;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridObject object = my.get(position);
        GridObject revers = reverseobj.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_set, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (check.get(position))  // used to be ...equals("true")
        {
            holder.text.setImageResource(revers.getName());
        }
        else {
            holder.text.setImageResource(object.getName());
        }
        // make items up to current level clickable
        convertView.setClickable(currentLevel < position);
        // show unclickable items as disabled
        convertView.setEnabled(currentLevel >= position);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return my.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // increase the current level if the item for the current level is clicked
        currentLevel = Math.max(currentLevel, position + 1);
        // toggle the checked state for the clicked item
        check.put(position, !check.get(position, false));
        // refresh the views
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

You can then enable this on your GridView in a similar way as before:

```
myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity());
gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(myAdapter);
```

Note that I have implemented the missing `check` list as a `SparseBooleanArray` rather than what looks like an array of strings with `"true"` and `"false"` values in your version.  You can change it back if you prefer.